# Can't parse a h265 stream

Tags: video-processing, video-capture, live555

I'm trying to parse a stream from a h265 camera. The live555 library give me frames which I get in afterGettingFrame(). There I parse them to get NALUs by their header "0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01". After I parse the next byte of NALU and get is it "I" frame or not:

```
  auto t = (buf[0] >> 1) & 0x3f;
  return t == 19 || t == 20;
```

And I get an example stream of NALUs:

```
log info Frame: time=1691746190593, key=true, duration=25230, size=50338
log info Frame: time=1691746190593, key=true, duration=3163, size=3464
log info Frame: time=1691746190713, key=false, duration=37765, size=480
log info Frame: time=1691746190713, key=false, duration=998, size=3274
log info Frame: time=1691746190713, key=false, duration=711, size=420
log info Frame: time=1691746190793, key=false, duration=115679, size=322
log info Frame: time=1691746190793, key=false, duration=1533, size=2437
log info Frame: time=1691746190793, key=false, duration=842, size=286
log info Frame: time=1691746190913, key=false, duration=77556, size=287
log info Frame: time=1691746190913, key=false, duration=1322, size=2693
log info Frame: time=1691746190913, key=false, duration=2059, size=216
log info Frame: time=1691746190993, key=false, duration=117100, size=258
log info Frame: time=1691746190993, key=false, duration=3076, size=2486
log info Frame: time=1691746190993, key=false, duration=396, size=211
log info Frame: time=1691746191113, key=false, duration=81118, size=23
log info Frame: time=1691746191113, key=false, duration=377, size=64
log info Frame: time=1691746191113, key=false, duration=3962, size=10
log info Frame: time=1691746191113, key=true, duration=5140, size=5069
log info Frame: time=1691746191113, key=true, duration=2797, size=49916
log info Frame: time=1691746191113, key=true, duration=1949, size=3493
log info Frame: time=1691746191193, key=false, duration=101536, size=429
log info Frame: time=1691746191193, key=false, duration=1158, size=3186
log info Frame: time=1691746191193, key=false, duration=1146, size=350
log info Frame: time=1691746191313, key=false, duration=77701, size=332
```

Here there are the frames with the same timestamp, but as far as I know, it's OK.
Futher, what should I do with them (frames with the same timestamp)? There are some ways: to concate them by timestamp or to parse by one. I tried both ways without success.
Decode as usual (which works for h264):

```
  AVPacket avpkt;
  av_init_packet(&avpkt);
  avpkt.pts = 0;
  avpkt.dts = 0;
  avpkt.data = data;
  avpkt.size = size;

  int gotFrame = false;

  while (avpkt.size > 0)
  {
    // We must use positive result to move through the data buffer
    auto len = avcodec_decode_video2(av_context_, av_frame_, &gotFrame, &avpkt);
    if (len < 0)
    {
      break;
    }

    avpkt.data += len;
    avpkt.size -= len;
  }
```

So, this code returns gotFrame=true, I make a jpeg and get a picture half green!
What is the right way to parse such a stream?

Comment: **(1)** I don't use Live555 but it seems to be caching (storing) frames and then sending, out to you, some multiple frames at the same time. That would explain the same UNIX timestamps for different frames (is it meaning _"time at receiving"_ or _"time at sending"_?). **(2)** _"I make a jpeg and get a picture half green!"_ Try and **decode a keyframe** only. If still green then either (a) you're decoding as **wrong colorspace**, or (b) you didn't **copy enough bytes** to make a complete picture (got all slices? got an interlaced frame?) or else (c) your metadata (SPS/PPS/etc) itself is wrong.

Comment: Now I concate I-frame parts, get an I frame, feed it to the decoder, which decodes without any errors, but again get a frame half green!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it. When I parsed the frames from live555, I removed the first header "0001", so result concataned frame didn't have them, only from the first NALU. But decoder demands to have all the NALU's headers, including the intermediate ones.